# jQuery UI Time Picker issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Ok, we are using the `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-0.9.3.js` file

Which has a nice pop up with the calendar and populates a input field.

The problem is, if the input field is already populated and say someone bring up the calendar and happens to click on the next month and clicks away from the calendar...the input field is updated with that next month even though the "DONE" button was not clicked on.

If anyone is familiar with this JS file...I would appreciate some help as to only be able to update the field if the "DONE" button was clicked after choosing a date...

```
    $(function()
{
    $("#publication_datepicker").datetimepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: '..images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+5Y',
        duration: '',
        <c:if test="${formIsReadonly or form.newsItemId == '-1'}">disabled: true,</c:if>
        constrainInput: false,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
    });
```

JS FILE:
[jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js](http://code.google.com/p/grsnippetgen/source/browse/scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js?spec=svnfd74d10955600eea2964cd11a83386457ff69fe0&r=fd74d10955600eea2964cd11a83386457ff69fe0)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem...in the js file there is a function called: _newInst

I commented out this line in 2 sections:

`tp_inst._updateDateTime(dp_inst)`

Fixed the problem

```
 _newInst: function ($input, o) {
        var tp_inst = new Timepicker(),
            inlineSettings = {};
        tp_inst.hour = tp_inst._defaults.hour;
        tp_inst.minute = tp_inst._defaults.minute;
        tp_inst.second = tp_inst._defaults.second;
        tp_inst.ampm = "";
        tp_inst.$input = $input;
        for (var attrName in this._defaults) {
            var attrValue = $input.attr("time:" + attrName);
            if (attrValue) {
                try {
                    inlineSettings[attrName] = eval(attrValue)
                } catch (err) {
                    inlineSettings[attrName] = attrValue
                }
            }
        }
        tp_inst._defaults = $.extend({}, this._defaults, inlineSettings, o, {
            beforeShow: function (input, dp_inst) {
                if ($.isFunction(o.beforeShow)) {
                    o.beforeShow(input, dp_inst, tp_inst)
                }
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, dp_inst) {
                //tp_inst._updateDateTime(dp_inst);
                if ($.isFunction(o.onChangeMonthYear)) {
                    o.onChangeMonthYear(year, month, dp_inst, tp_inst)
                }
            },
            onClose: function (dateText, dp_inst) {
                if (tp_inst.timeDefined === true && $input.val() != "") {
                    //tp_inst._updateDateTime(dp_inst)
                }
                if ($.isFunction(o.onClose)) {
                    o.onClose(dateText, dp_inst, tp_inst)
                }
            },
            timepicker: tp_inst
        });
        if (o.altField) {
            tp_inst.$altInput = $(o.altField).css({
                cursor: "pointer"
            }).focus(function () {
                $input.trigger("focus")
            })
        }
        if (tp_inst._defaults.minDate !== undefined && tp_inst._defaults.minDate instanceof Date) {
            tp_inst._defaults.minDateTime = new Date(tp_inst._defaults.minDate.getTime())
        }
        if (tp_inst._defaults.minDateTime !== undefined && tp_inst._defaults.minDateTime instanceof Date) {
            tp_inst._defaults.minDate = new Date(tp_inst._defaults.minDateTime.getTime())
        }
        if (tp_inst._defaults.maxDate !== undefined && tp_inst._defaults.maxDate instanceof Date) {
            tp_inst._defaults.maxDateTime = new Date(tp_inst._defaults.maxDate.getTime())
        }
        if (tp_inst._defaults.maxDateTime !== undefined && tp_inst._defaults.maxDateTime instanceof Date) {
            tp_inst._defaults.maxDate = new Date(tp_inst._defaults.maxDateTime.getTime())
        }
        return tp_inst
    }
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this - you really saved me a lot of time digging into this issue. It seems strange that it was coded this way and it still seems to be the same with version 1.4.1. I would have thought it would make sense to make it work the same way as the standard datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (not tested):

```
   $("#publication_datepicker").datetimepicker(
        {
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: '../chassis/images/calendar.gif',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: '+5Y',
            duration: '',
            <c:if test="${formIsReadonly or form.newsItemId == '-1'}">disabled: true,</c:if>
            constrainInput: false,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
        });

 $.datepicker.unbind('blur');
```

Comment: datetimepicker extend datepicker, i mean datepicker!

Comment: `$.datetimepicker.unbind('blur');` is null or not an object